# Turning a Pandas series into JSON while preserving column names

Tags: python, json, pandas

**The short version:**

I'm trying to go from a Pandas `Series` to a JSON array with objects representation without losing column names in the process.

**Long story:**

I'm using `groupby` on a column of a `DataFrame` (which, to my knowledge, results in a `Series` - yet this may be the first wrong turn I take).

```python
year_dist = df.groupby(df['year']).size()
year_dist.name = 'amount' # Name of the aggregate column
```

The resulting data (`Series`?) looks like this:

```
year
1990  10
1992  20
1995  15
1996  8
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Its simple and very straightforward, exactly what I want. Now I wish to convert this into JSON by means of chaining `to_json()`. This is also no problem and the default behavior will yield:

```js
{"1990":10,"1992":20,"1995":15,"1996":8}
```

Yet, I would like to keep the column names (column and series name) of this series during JSON conversion, effectively making a string like this:

```js
[{year: "1990", amount :10}, {year:"1992", amount:20}, {year: "1995", amount:15}, {year:"1996", amount:8}]
```

A JSON array with objects, each with a `year` and `amount` keys.

The only way I have partially accomplished this is by adding in an index column and reformatting the JSON output by using the `orient` keyword:

```python
year_dist = year_dist.reset_index().to_json(orient='index')
```

Which yields:

```js
{"0":{"year":1990,"amount":10},"1":{"year":1992,"amount":20},"2":{"year":1995,"amount":15},"3":{"year":1996,"amount":8}}
```

Almost perfect, yet now I have the extraneous index added in front of every object in my JSON string (and the whole is wrapped in yet another object).

Any pointers as to how to accomplish this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What you are calling a "column name" is actually the name of the index itself.  A Series by definition is a one-dimensional object and doesn't have columns per se.

Comment: @BranBarn Thank you for clearing that up. It thus acts more like a single level dictionary in Python ... Yet when I assign a name to the `Series` and convert it into JSON by using an `index` orientation, it somehow "gets" that the year is named `year` and the aggregate is named `amount`.

Comment: Yes.  I mostly was mentioning that because it may help you to interpret the documentation and find a solution.  But I posted an answer that I think does what you want.

Comment: Yep, answer is indeed perfect and it made the `Series`/`DataFrame` difference click ... awesome. Thanks for not only the direct solution but also the extra understanding - which to me is more valuable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you need is to use `reset_index` to make a DataFrame, then use `orient="records"`:

```
x = pandas.Series([1, 2, 3], index=["A", "B", "C"])
x.index.name = "stuff"
x.name = "cruddo"

>>> print(x)
stuff
A    1
B    2
C    3
Name: cruddo, dtype: int64
>>> x.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
[{"stuff":"A","cruddo":1},{"stuff":"B","cruddo":2},{"stuff":"C","cruddo":3}]'
```

Comment: Aha, this indeed works like a charm. I guess my confusion was the difference between `Series` and `DataFrame` as applying a `records` orientation to a `Series` simply returns the values. I wasn't aware that by using `reset_index()` you convert it back to a `DataFrame` (and thus `records` will yield different output) ... but in hindsight this makes sense since you are applying a new dimension to your data: the new index.